# Extending an algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $A \subseteq B$ commutative $R$-algebras such that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, and let $C$ be any $R$-algebra. Let $f: A \to C$ be an $R$-algebra homomorphism.

Is it possible to extend $f$ to an $R$-algebra homomorphism $F: B \to C$? Namely, is it possible to find an $R$-algebra homomorphism $F: B \to C$ such that $F|A=f$). (In other words, if $B=A[b_1,\ldots,b_n]$, how to define $F(b_i)$?).

The problem is that we probably have relations in $B$ which their images under 
$F$ should satisfy.

A special case (if the above question does not have a good answer): 
$A$ and $B$ are noetherian integral domains having the same field of fractions, $B=A[w]$, where $w^{n+1}=a_nw^n+\ldots+a_1w+a_0$, $a_i \in A$, and $w= a/a'$ where $a,a' \in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=A=C=\Bbb Z$, $B=\Bbb Z[i]$ (Gauss' integers) and $f:\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z$ the identity.

The map $f$ does not extend to a map $\Bbb Z[i]\rightarrow\Bbb Z$ as the latter would be surjective but $\Bbb Z$ is not a quotient ring of $\Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: Thanks! So you have given a nice answer (in the negative) to the general case. Do you think there is a chance to solve the special case I have mentioned? ($A$ and $B$ have the same field of fractions etc.) ?

Comment: Well, if $R=A=C=\Bbb Z$ and $f={\rm id}_{\Bbb Z}$ again, how would you extend $f$ to a map ${\Bbb Z}[\frac12]\rightarrow\Bbb Z$? You cannot ....

Comment: Thanks! But in the special case I have mentioned, $B$ is integral over $A$.

Comment: Even if $B$ is a domain integral over $A$, extending the identity map $A\rightarrow A$ is impossible. Indeed, if $B=A[b]\simeq A[T]/(f(T))$ where $f(T)$ is monic an extension $B\rightarrow A$ of ${\rm id}_A$ would have to send $b$ to some root (in $A$) of $f(T)$. But $f(T)$ has no root in $A$ or else $B$ wouldn't be a domain (assuming $\deg(f)>1$, of course).

Comment: Thanks again! I now noticed that I should have demanded that $C$ will not be semiprime. However, your answers are nice; you should not have guessed that $C$ is not semiprime-- especially since I originally wrote "let $C$ be any $R$-algebra". Maybe I will explain later the motivation to my question (it is related to formal smoothness).